# How to sort files by their dates into timestamped folders?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, newlines

I want to sort about 2500 images every day into folders with a timestamp.
So far I have this script but it's not working....

```
for x in *.jpg; do
d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p "$d"
mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```

The error is:

```
/home/pi/BRAVO/sort.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'home/pi/BRAVO/sort.sh: line 1: `for x in *.jpg; do
```

Any solution to this problem or a similar script?

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < script > script_fixed`

Comment: You have odd line endings (`\r`) from DOS, presumably...